# Android : Registering and unregistering a broadcast receiver(ACTION_TIME_CLICK) from widget

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I registered a receiver for ACTION_TIME_TICK intent dynamically from widget.But after 10/15 minutes application crashed and device rebooted. Below are the code:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context) {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
        context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
}
```

My broadcast receiver is by which i update my all widget:

```
    public class WReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Toast.makeText(context, "[onReceive]", 5).show();
            AppWidgetManager widgetMgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            int [] widgetIds = widgetMgr.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, WidgetManager.class));
            //
            for(int appWidgetId : widgetIds) {
                WidgetManager.updateAppWidget(context, widgetMgr, appWidgetId, "World Clock");
            }
    }
      }
```

This is works for around 15 to 20 minutes only. Should i unregister the receiver if so where should i register in widget?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Do the receiver registration in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, not in `onUpdate`: if you do it there you will repeatedly register the same receiver every time the widget provider calls, which will exhaust the available resources on your device.</strike>

EDIT: as @haimg pointed out (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK), this should actually be done in `onEnabled`, not `onUpdate`. Your crash is because you repeatedly registered for the the Intent every time `onUpdate` got called, instead of exactly once (which `onEnabled` would do).

Comment: Actually, you cannot register for ACTION_TIME_TICK in the manifest. Need to do it in the onEnabled().